# Cant dissmis email when attaching screenshot xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, ios5, email-attachments

when I email a screenshot from my app I cant dimiss the email client when its called. Even if I hit cancel nothing happens, could someone advise me on what im doing wrong please.

```
- (void)btn:(id)sender {


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] self];
    mailComposer.delegate = self;
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];



    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];

}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate as `mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;`

Then call the dismiss method in the mail composer delegate method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    // Do any processing before dismissing
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, finally sorted it thanks to your advice, Very grateful! Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working! Don't forget to accept the answer if you consider it correct. Thanks!